# Mathematica has trouble solving this coupled differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I'm trying to solve the coupled differential equations:

```
GTISE = FullSimplify[DSolve[{{
     {(-I γ + δ1) ab[t] - A E^(-I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) db[t] - 
        2 I Derivative[1][ab][t] == 0},
     {(-I γ - δ1) bb[t] - A E^(-I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) cb[t] - 
        2 I Derivative[1][bb][t] == 0},
     {-A E^(I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) bb[t] + (-2 J - I γ + δ2) cb[t] - 
        2 I Derivative[1][cb][t] == 0},
     {-A E^(I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) ab[t] - (2 J + I γ + δ2) db[t] - 
        2 I Derivative[1][db][t] == 0}
    } , ab[0] ==  ab0, bb[0] ==  bb0, cb[0] ==  cb0, 
    db[0] ==  db0}, {ab[t], bb[t], cb[t], db[t]}, t]
```

And *Mathematica* just returns the same statement. Am I doing anything wrong or is *Mathematica* just unable to solve this symbolically?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it surprising that `DSolve` cannot obtain a solution for this system of linear ODEs without human assistance.  The solution can be obtained as follows.  First, name the four ODEs for convenience.

```
eq = Flatten@
    {{{(-I γ + δ1) ab[t] - A E^(-I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) db[t] - 2 I ab'[t] == 0}, 
     {(-I γ - δ1) bb[t] - A E^(-I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) cb[t] - 2 I bb'[t] == 0}, 
     {-A E^(I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) bb[t] + (-2 J - I γ + δ2) cb[t] - 2 I cb'[t] == 0},
     {-A E^(I t (Ωo1 - Ωo2)) ab[t] - (2 J + I γ + δ2) db[t] - 2 I db'[t] == 0}}};
```

Now, note that the first and fourth equations are decoupled from the second and third, and can be solved independently.  Unfortunately, `DSolve` is unable to solve even these pairs of ODEs.  Yet, if the first and fourth equations are combined into a single second-order ODE, `DSolve` can solve it!

```
sdb = Solve[eq[[1]], db[t]][[1, 1, 2]];
Simplify[eq[[4]] /. db -> (Function[t, z] /. z -> sdb)];
rab = DSolve[%, ab, t, GeneratedParameters -> C1][[1, 1]]
(* ab -> Function[{t}, E^(1/4 I t (2 J + 2 I γ - δ1 + δ2 - 2 Ωo1 + 2 Ωo2 + 
       I Sqrt[-4 A^2 - 4 J^2 - 4 J δ1 - δ1^2 - 4 J δ2 - 2 δ1 δ2 - δ2^2 + 
       8 J Ωo1 + 4 δ1 Ωo1 + 4 δ2 Ωo1 - 4 Ωo1^2 - 8 J Ωo2 - 4 δ1 Ωo2 - 
       4 δ2 Ωo2 + 8 Ωo1 Ωo2 - 4 Ωo2^2])) C1[1] + 
       E^(1/4 I t (2 J + 2 I γ - δ1 + δ2 - 2 Ωo1 + 2 Ωo2 - 
       I Sqrt[-4 A^2 - 4 J^2 - 4 J δ1 - δ1^2 - 4 J δ2 - 2 δ1 δ2 - δ2^2 + 
       8 J Ωo1 + 4 δ1 Ωo1 + 4 δ2 Ωo1 - 4 Ωo1^2 - 8 J Ωo2 - 4 δ1 Ωo2 - 
       4 δ2 Ωo2 + 8 Ωo1 Ωo2 - 4 Ωo2^2])) C1[2]] *)
```

Next, back-substitute this result in `sdb` to obtain the corresponding solution for `db`.

```
Collect[sdb /. rab, C[_], Simplify];
rdb = db -> (Function[t, z] /. z -> %)
```

The answer is not reproduced here, because it is even lengthier than that for `ab`.  The solutions for the remaining two variables are determined similarly.

```
scb = Solve[eq[[2]], cb[t]][[1, 1, 2]];
Simplify[eq[[3]] /. cb -> (Function[t, z] /. z -> scb)];
rbb = DSolve[%, bb, t, GeneratedParameters -> C2][[1, 1]]
```

and

```
Collect[scb /. rbb, C[_], Simplify];
rcb = cb -> (Function[t, z] /. z -> %)
```

Again, the results are not given here for the sake of brevity.  The results can, of course, be verified by

```
Simplify[eq /. {rab, rbb, rcb, rdb}]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Finally, the boundary conditions are applied.

```
Solve[{ab0 == Last[rab][0], bb0 == Last[rbb][0], ac0 == Last[rcb][0], 
    ad0 == Last[rdb][0]}, {C1[1], C1[2], C2[1], C2[2]}] // Flatten // Simplify
(* {C1[1] -> (-2 I A ad0 + ab0 (2 I J + I δ1 + I δ2 - 2 I Ωo1 + 2 I Ωo2 + 
        Sqrt[-4 A^2 - (2 J + δ1 + δ2 - 2 Ωo1 + 2 Ωo2)^2]))/
        (2 Sqrt[-4 A^2 - (2 J + δ1 + δ2 - 2 Ωo1 + 2 Ωo2)^2]), 
     . . . } *)
```

The actual computations take less than a minute.

Comment: Very nice. Random note, but your `(Function[t, z] /. z -> %)` could `Function[t, Evaluate[%]]` instead.

Comment: @b3m2a1  Yes, they both work.  Thanks.  By the way, I truly find it amazing that `DSolve` cannot handle such simple problems.